# Selenium implicit wait functionality on page reload

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, reload

I am writing a test where i look for an element on the page and then reload the page.

Steps :

- Open firefox browser using selenium webdriver(java).Implicit wait is set to 30 seconds.
- Navigate to a webpage . Verify if the element with `id="elementid"` 
  exists.
- Now reload the page .  Verify if the element with `id="elementid"`
  exists.

I would like to know the behaviour in the following usecase.

**

- Incase if the reload is not proper and the page that is displayed is
  the old page and not the reloaded one , will the selenium return true
  when i verify for the presence of element with `id="elementid"` even
  though the page instance is an old one ? Or will it throw an exception ?

**

Comment: Specify what do you mean under 'reload is not proper'

Comment: By reload is not proper, i mean the page reload did not happen and the page displayed in the browser is still the older instance only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options:

- page reload didn't happen between you trigger the reload and look up the element again
- page reload happened (and finished) between you trigger the reload and look up the element again
- page reload happened (but didn't finish) between you trigger the reload and look up the element again

Depending on if Selenium assigned internal element ID after page was reloaded and not, you can have StaleElementReferenceException or not.

This is how I'd handle it in my framework:

- create waitForPageToLoad() method for every single Page Object you interact with, and call it before any other method on this page; this method should wait until certain (unique for this page) element is present (or displayed)
- call this method between triggering page reload and another element lookup
- create wrapper methods for typical element intaractions (click, sendKeys etc), handle StaleElementReferenceException on that level (usually by explicit wait and re-doing the same interaction, there is no other way to handle this class of exception)

Check how it goes, add verification of unique page element if possible (if there is any unique page element which is present after page reload, but not before), add explicit wait before 2nd element lookup if necessary.

Comment: Hi , 
I have set the implicit timeout and pageload timeout to 30 seconds in the code. 
So incase if the reload of the page does not complete in the 30 seconds and still the old page instance is shown in browser, will selenium now look for the webelements on the older page and pass the test as they are present or will it throw an exception as the page did not load in time.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the page is a old one or new one or loaded partially.It will only throw an exception if the element is not present in the DOM of the page.Well that's how Selenium works

And it will return true if you verify the presence of element if it is in DOM

> FindElement
>   This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the
>   time of execution. The findElement(..) invocation will return a
>   matching row, or try again repeatedly until the configured timeout is
>   reached.

Comment: If the pageload time is crossed but the page did not load and still the old instance is shown  , then will selenium throw an exception or will it look for the elements specified in the findElement and pass the test as the elements are present in the older instance which is currently displayed due to the failure of page load.

Comment: As mentioned it will try to look in the DOM it doesn't matter it loaded or not.Yes it will pass if the element is there

Answer (score 0):

It will attempt to search for an element anyway.

In case it suddenly disappears - you get `StaleElementReferenceException`
In case it is not there - `NoSuchElementException`

If you think that a fact of (not)reloading page matters for your test and you really want to know (or take appropriate actions), check it with `document.readyState` to be `complete` (when loaded) or not `complete` (while still loading)